# How to use JavaScript in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Can you please suggest couple of complex use cases for JavaScript in Google Analytics which are not achievable through Google Tag Manager?

Comment: you use javascript to manipulate ga and gtm in client side. what do you mean complex use cases?

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky Thanks for your reply.                         For example, by adding this code                        ga('send', 'page', '/ajax-url');                               We are able to track ajax calls. Like that, is there anything which we can achieve through javascript and which are not possible through google tag manager?

Comment: but `ga('send', 'page', ..')` is javascript, so you're already using it

Comment: basically, if you want to report anything dynamic (or trigger report on interactions), you'd use some sort of javascript to trigger the correct ga/gtm callbacks

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky Yeah exactly. Instead of this simple implementation, I want a complex use case of javascript.

Comment: I'm willing to be most of your use cases are possible in GTM. Your question won't get the answers you're looking for without specific use cases/code.

Comment: Tracking every "x" seconds or every "x" percent worth of video or audio played.  Tracking video start/stop events.  Tracking page scroll events.  Tracking complex form interactions with validation rules residing on the client and/or server.